# Defining operator< for a struct

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I sometimes use small `structs` as keys in maps, and so I have to define an `operator<` for them.  Usually, this ends up looking something like this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;

    bool operator<(const MyStruct& rhs) const
    {
        if (a < rhs.a)
        {
           return true;
        }
        else if (a == rhs.a)
        {
            if (b < rhs.b)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (b == rhs.b)
            {
                return c < rhs.c;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

This seems awfully verbose and error-prone.  Is there a better way, or some easy way to automate definition of `operator<` for a `struct` or `class`?

I know some people like to just use something like `memcmp(this, &rhs, sizeof(MyStruct)) < 0`, but this may not work correctly if there are padding bytes between the members, or if there are `char` string arrays that may contain garbage after the null terminators.

Comment: You can have brevity that's not significantly more error-prone: `return (a < rhs.a || (a == rhs.a && (b < rhs.b || (b == rhs.b && c < rhs.c))));`

Comment: BTW. since your first `if` clause actually returns, there is no need for a `else` keyword. Same for the inner code block. You can just drop the word `else` in both instances.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

This is quite an old question and as a consequence all answers here are obsolete. C++11 allows a more elegant and efficient solution:

```
bool operator <(const MyStruct& x, const MyStruct& y) {
    return std::tie(x.a, x.b, x.c) < std::tie(y.a, y.b, y.c);
}
```

Why is this better than using `boost::make_tuple`? Because `make_tuple` will create copies of all the data members, which can be costly. [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie), by contrast, will just create a thin wrapper of references (which the compiler will probably optimise away entirely).

In fact, the above code should now be considered the idiomatic solution to implementing a lexicographical compare for structures with several data members.

Comment: Worth mentioning that the above code won't work - operator < takes only one argument.  ```operator<(const MyStruct& rhs)```

Comment: @Riot No, the code works just fine. It does, however, need to be defined outside of `MyStruct` – this is best practice anyway.

Comment: Fair enough - i was just going by the code in the original question.

Comment: With large struct and c++1y, you can add a function `auto AsTuple(const MyStruct & s) { return std::tie(s.x, s.y); }`. This avoid repeating the fields of the struct in the `operator<`.... unfortunatly I did not see anyway to do it in c++11.

Comment: @Renaud In C++11 you can use a lambda (`auto as_tuple = [](MyStruct const& s) {return std::tie(s.x, s.y);};`), because that can infer the return type.

Comment: Using `std::tie` as part of operator() in a map must be adjusted to support antisymmetry and transitvity. Otherwise comparing structs: x < y == !(y <= x) wouldn't be always true.

Comment: @fcatho My code implements a lexicographical compare. And lexicographical compare is a strict weak ordering, which *is* antisymmetric and transitive.

Answer (score 20):

Others have mentioned `boost::tuple`, which gives you a lexicographical comparison. If you want to keep it as a structure with named elements, you can create temporary tuples for comparison:

```
bool operator<(const MyStruct& x, const MyStruct& y)
{
    return boost::make_tuple(x.a,x.b,x.c) < boost::make_tuple(y.a,y.b,y.c);
}
```

In C++0x, this becomes `std::make_tuple()`.

UPDATE: And now C++11 is here, it becomes `std::tie()`, to make a tuple of references without copying the objects. See Konrad Rudolph's new answer for details.

Comment: I'm wondering how much constructing those tuple objects affects performance.

Comment: @Timo: The construction and comparison *should* be inlined, so I'd be surprised if it was slower than comparing the values directly. But the only way to be sure is to measure it.

Comment: This is still good if you need to compare `x.geta(), x.getb(), x.getc()` or other functions that return references. Haven't been able to use tie for that.

Answer (score 8):

I would do this:

```
#define COMPARE(x) if((x) < (rhs.x)) return true; \
                   if((x) > (rhs.x)) return false;
COMPARE(a)
COMPARE(b)
COMPARE(c)
return false;
#undef COMPARE
```

Comment: Just the sort of thing that can't be replaced by templates, because you need to return from the enclosing function. One suggestion: replace `(x) > (rhs.x)` with `(rhs.x) < (x)` to only rely on `operator<` on the members. Also I think the parentheses are redundant, I can't see how this macro would work properly with input that required them.

Comment: I'd replace the final `COMPARE(c); return false;` with `return c < rhs.c`, to avoid the extraneous > comparison.

Comment: You're right. It's a matter of compromise between easiness of reading and efficiency.

Comment: if you don't care about readability why the the if?
COMPARE(X,def) (!(rhs.x < x) && (x < rhs.x)) && def;
return COMPARE(a,COMPARE(b,COMPARE(c,true)));
But then again why try to guess what's faster. code, compile, time and then _potentially_ optimze and readable code is so much easier to optimize

Answer (score 6):

In this case  you can use `boost::tuple<int, int, int>` - its [operator<](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html#relational_operators) works just the way you want.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is to stick with the < operator for all comparisons and don't use > or ==.  Below is the pattern I follow, and you can follow for all your structs

```
typedef struct X
{
    int a;
    std::string b;
    int c;
    std::string d;

    bool operator <( const X& rhs ) const
    {
        if (a < rhs.a) { return true; }
        else if ( rhs.a < a ) { return false; }

        // if neither of the above were true then 
        // we are consdidered equal using strict weak ordering
        // so we move on to compare the next item in the struct

        if (b < rhs.b) { return true; }
        if ( rhs.b < b ) { return false; }

        if (c < rhs.c) { return true; }
        if ( rhs.c < c ) { return false; }

        if (d < rhs.d) { return true; }
        if ( rhs.d < d ) { return false; }

        // if both are completely equal (based on strict weak ordering)
        // then just return false since equality doesn't yield less than
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: What do you need the elses for?

Comment: Really like the idea that < operator needs to be defined in terms of itself.

Answer (score 3):

The best way I know is to use a [boost tuple](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/tuple/doc/tuple_users_guide.html). It offers among others a builtin comparison and constructors.

```
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple_comparison.hpp>

typedef boost::tuple<int,int,int> MyStruct;

MyStruct x0(1,2,3), x1(1,2,2);
if( x0 < x1 )
   ...
```

I also like Mike Seymors [suggestion to use temporary tuples through boost's make_tuple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882467/defining-operator-for-a-struct/3882550#3882550)

Comment: Yes… but does it perform well then, when it is about complex structures?

Comment: Why shouldn't it perfom well? The work happens at compile time.

Answer (score 3):

I usually implement lexicographical ordering this way:

```
bool operator < (const MyObject& obj)
{
    if( first != obj.first ){
        return first < obj.first;
    }
    if( second != obj.second ){
        return second < obj.second;
    }
    if( third != obj.third ){
        return third < obj.third
    }
    ...
}
```

Mind you it needs extra consideration for floating point values (G++ warnings), for those something like this would be better:

```
bool operator < (const MyObject& obj)
{
    if( first < obj.first ){
        return true;
    }
    if( first > obj.first ){
        return false;
    }
    if( second < obj.second ){
        return true;
    }
    if( second > obj.second ){
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/less.hpp>

struct MyStruct {
   int a, b, c;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( MyStruct,
                           ( int, a )
                           ( int, b )
                           ( int, c )
                          )

bool operator<( const MyStruct &s1, const MyStruct &s2 )
{
   return boost::fusion::less( s1, s2 );
}

int main()
{
   MyStruct s1 = { 0, 4, 8 }, s2 = { 0, 4, 9 };
   std::cout << ( s1 < s2 ? "is less" : "is not less" ) << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if you can't use boost, you could try something like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct is_gt
{
  is_gt(const T& l, const T&r) : _s(l > r) {}

  template <typename T2>
  inline is_gt<T>& operator()(const T2& l, const T2& r)
  {
    if (!_s)
    {
      _s = l > r;
    }
    return *this;
  }

  inline bool operator!() const { return !_s; }

  bool _s;
};

struct foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;

  friend bool operator<(const foo& l, const foo& r);
};

bool operator<(const foo& l, const foo& r)
{
  return !is_gt<int>(l.a, r.a)(l.b, r.b)(l.c, r.c);
}

int main(void)
{
  foo s1 = { 1, 4, 8 }, s2 = { 2, 4, 9 };
  cout << "s1 < s2: " << (s1 < s2) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I guess this avoids any macros, and as long as the types in the structure support <, it should work. Of course there is overhead for this approach, constructing is_gt and then superflous branches for each parameter if one of the values is greater...

**Edit:**

Modified based on comments, this version should now short-circuit as well, now uses two bools to keep state (not sure there's a way to do this with a single bool).

```
template <typename T>
struct is_lt
{
  is_lt(const T& l, const T&r) : _s(l < r), _e(l == r) {}

  template <typename T2>
  inline bool operator()(const T2& l, const T2& r)
  {
    if (!_s && _e)
    {
      _s = l < r;
      _e = l == r;
    }
    return _s;
  }

  inline operator bool() const { return _s; }

  bool _s;
  bool _e;
};
```

and

```
bool operator<(const foo& l, const foo& r)
{
  is_lt<int> test(l.a, r.a);
  return test || test(l.b, r.b) || test(l.c, r.c);
}
```

just build up a collection of such functors for various comparisons..

Comment: Will this work properly if the two structs are equal? operator<() should return false in that case, but it looks to me that you are only checking for not-greater-than.

Comment: This approach does not allow for short-circuit evaluation - any way to work that in?

Comment: @mskfisher - can do I guess, but, thinking about it some more... all these really complicated methods are kind of pointless, what you need is the || operator! i.e., return l.a < r.a || l.b < r.b || l.c < r.c; see edit above...

Comment: That new `||` method does not work for the case where `l.a > r.a` and `l.b < r.b` - it should return `false`, but it will return `true`.

Comment: @mskfisher, oops, you're right - long day... the final edit should have a short-circuited version, now the operator is not a one liner...

Answer (score 1):

I just learned the `boost::tuple` trick, thanks, @Mike Seymour!

If you can't afford Boost, my favorite idiom is:

```
bool operator<(const MyStruct& rhs) const
{
    if (a < rhs.a)  return true;
    if (a > rhs.a)  return false;

    if (b < rhs.b)  return true;
    if (b > rhs.b)  return false;

    return (c < rhs.c);
}
```

which I like because it sets everything in parallel structure that makes errors and omissions easier to spot.

But, of course, you are unit testing this anyway, right?

Comment: Note that this is essentially the same as @Benoit's answer, without the macros, so the comments on that answer apply here as well.

Comment: Thanks.  @Mark Ransom's point about solely using `<` is duly noted.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a perl script to help me. For example given:

```
class A
{
int a;
int b;
int c;
```

It would emit:

```
bool operator<(const A& left, const A& right)
{
    bool result(false);

    if(left.a != right.a)
    {
        result = left.a < right.a;
    }
    else if(left.b != right.b)
    {
        result = left.b < right.b;
    }
    else
    {
        result = left.c < right.c;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Code (it's a bit long):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

main:

my $line = <>;
chomp $line;
$line =~ s/^ *//;

my ($temp, $line, $temp) = split / /, $line;

print "bool operator<(const $line& left, const $line& right)\n{\n";
print "    bool result(false);\n\n";

my $ifText = "if";

$line = <>;

while($line)
{
    if($line =~ /{/)
    {
        $line = <>;
        next;
    }
    if($line =~ /}/)
    {
        last;
    }

    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/^ *//;

    my ($type, $name) = split / /, $line;
    $name =~ s/; *$//;

    $line = <>;
    if($line && !($line =~ /}/))
    {
        print "    $ifText(left.$name != right.$name)\n";
        print "    {\n";
        print "        result = left.$name < right.$name;\n";
        print "    }\n";

        $ifText = "else if";
    }
    else
    {
        print "    else\n";
        print "    {\n";
        print "        result = left.$name < right.$name;\n";
        print "    }\n";

        last;
    }
}

print "\n    return result;\n}\n";
```

Comment: It's usually more common for objects to be unequal, so I'd modify your comparisons to test using op< first.

Comment: @Roger Pate agreed, but I can't quite visualize how the code would look then, could you elaborate briefly?

Comment: `if (left.a != left.b) { return left.a < left.b; }` becomes `if (left.a < left.b) return true; else if (left.a != left.b) return false;` (or you can use the result variable, same thing)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool operator <(const A& l, const A& r)
{

    int[] offsets = { offsetof(A, a), offsetof(A, b), offsetof(A, c) };
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(offsets)/sizeof(int); i++)
    {
        int ta = *(int*)(((const char*)&l)+offsets[i]);
        int tb = *(int*)(((const char*)&r)+offsets[i]);

        if (ta < tb)
             return true;
        else if (ta > tb)
             break;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what if there are more than 3 members

Comment: simple -> just add their offsets to the `offsets` array

Comment: If you were going to use this to implement op<, you might as well make the members into an array in the first place, then the comparison would be straight-forward (just use std::lexicographical_compare on both arrays).  This is a poor solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you can produce iterators over the elements defining the lexicographic order you can use `std::lexicographic_compare`, from `<algorithm>`.

Otherwise I suggest basing comparisons on old three-value compare functions, e.g. as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

int compared( int a, int b )
{
    return (a < b? -1 : a == b? 0 : +1);
}

struct MyStruct
{
    friend int compared( MyStruct const&, MyStruct const& );
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    bool operator<( MyStruct const& rhs ) const
    {
        return (compared( *this, rhs ) < 0);
    }
};

int compared( MyStruct const& lhs, MyStruct const& rhs )
{
    if( int x = compared( lhs.a, rhs.a ) ) { return x; }
    if( int x = compared( lhs.b, rhs.b ) ) { return x; }
    if( int x = compared( lhs.c, rhs.c ) ) { return x; }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    MyStruct const  s1 = { 0, 4, 8 };
    MyStruct const  s2 = { 0, 4, 9 };
    std::cout << ( s1 < s2 ? "is less" : "is not less" ) << std::endl;
}
```

I included the last `if` and `return` in the `compare` function just for generality. I imagine it can help maintenance to very rigidly adhere to a single system. Otherwise you could just do a `return compared( lhs.c, rhs.c )` there (and perhaps you prefer that).

Cheers & hth.,

− Alf

Answer (score 0):

If three-way comparisons are more expensive than two-way, and if the more-significant portions of the structures will often be equal, it may be helpful to define field comparison functions with a 'bias' parameter, such that if 'bias' is false, they will return true when a>b, and when bias is true, they will return true if a>=b.  Then one can find out if a>b by doing something like:

```
  return compare1(a.f1,b.f1, compare2(a.f2,b.f2, compare3(a.f3,b.f3,false)));
```

Note that all comparisons will be performed, even if a.f1<>b.f1, but comparisons will be two-way instead of three-way.