# overloading operator< for a multi field class

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, operator-overloading

I'm trying to insert into a map, where the key is a class.  I've overloaded the operator< function in my class as below:

```
struct MyType
{
    int a, b, c;
    bool operator<(const MyType& Rhs) const
    {
       return (a<Rhs.a) || (b<Rhs.b) || (c<Rhs.c);
    }
}
```

But for certain (unique) keys, values are being overwritten in the map.

What is the preferred operator< method for a multi value key?

I've seen [Defining operator< for a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882467/defining-operator-for-a-struct) which uses a tuple, but I'd rather write it long hand if I can.

Comment: Your order is not a strict weak order. You must not use this class as a key for a `std::map` as it is written.

Comment: @KerrekSB What is a strict weak order?

Comment: Something you can [discover on the internet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) :-) Or search this website for hundreds of duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
(a<Rhs.a) || (b<Rhs.b) || (c<Rhs.c)
```

does not create a strict weak ordering: suppose `a > Rhs.a`, but `b < Rhs.b`. Your expression returns `true`, yet it should be `false`: `b` should be used to resolve ties only when `a`s are the same, and then `c`s should be used only when `a`s and `b`s are the same.

This leads to the following "staircase" expression:

```
(a<Rhs.a) ||
(a==Rhs.a && b<Rhs.b) ||
(a==Rhs.a && b==Rhs.b && c<Rhs.c)
```

This is the long way of writing [the expression suggested in Kerrek SB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13880410/335858), which I recommend you to use for its far superior readability.

Comment: It seems the version of boost I have to use (1.33.1) doesn't support this, so I'll have to implement it long hand.  Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Do this instead:

```
return std::tie(a, b, c) < std::tie(Rhs.a, Rhs.b, Rhs.c);
```

You need to `#include <tuple>`.

Comment: I'd rather not use a tuple.

Comment: @Kerrek: Please explain that a bit so the OP can understand why it would work.

Comment: +1 I assume that you'd explain the "strict weak order" thing from your comment, too.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: There are too many duplicates of this topic on SO already. The OP is invited to search the site for a deeper explanation made by better people.

Comment: @Neil: Do it anyway. The code uses references only, so there's basically no cost. Unless you fancy news headlines like "Child reinvents wheel. Scientists baffled."

Comment: I'm using an old gcc, so can't use C++11, and my boost (1.33.1) doesn't support operator< for tuples.  
I'm going to have to go with @dasblinkenlight's idea.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if you instance two `MyType` like say for example `M1 = {1, 1, 2}` and `M2 = {1, 2, 1}` you have the unfortunate situation that `M1 < M2` **and** `M2 < M1`!

In order to fix this you need to assign `a` `b` and `c` some significance/order:

```
struct MyType
{
    int a, b, c;
    bool operator<(const MyType& Rhs) const
    {
       if (a < Rhs.a) return true;
       if (a > Rhs.a) return false;
       if (b < Rhs.b) return true;
       if (b > Rhs.b) return false;
       return c < Rhs.c;
    }
}
```

(This is a less optimal way to write the expression in dasblinkenlight's answer but maybe easier to understand).

But once you've understood why this is needed you should switch to a `tuple`, this really is boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need map with key of that type and do not need comparator, you might want to use boost::unordered_map and define hasher for your type using boost::hash_combine