# Accessing a partitioned vector within a map

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, stdmap, partition

I have an input file which has the following structure

```
#Latitude   Longitude   Depth [m]   Bathy depth [m] CaCO3 [%] ...
-78 -177    0   693 1
-78 -173    0   573 2
.
.
```

I have created a map, which has a key based on a `string` (the name of an *ocean basin*) and a value which contains a vector of the data. Now I need to sort the vectors by `bathyDepth`. To be precise, I would like to partition the vectors so that I can have a partition between all data rows with a depth between `0` and `500m`, `500m` and `1500m`, `1000m` and `2000m`...

I have stored the data into the *map* structure, but I'm unsure of how to store and access the partition so that I can then `cout` a data point at a particular depth.

My attempt:

```
//Define each basin spatially
//North Atlantic
double NAtlat1 = 0,  NAtlong1 = -70, NAtlat2 = 75, NAtlong2 = -15;
//South Atlantic and the rest...
double SPLIT = 0;

struct Point
{
   //structure Sample code/label--Lat--Long--SedimentDepth[m]--BathymetricDepth[m]--CaCO3[%]--CO3freefraction (SiO2 carb free)[%]--biogenic silica (bSiO2)[%]--Quartz[%]--CO3 ion[umol/l]--CO3critical[umol/l]--Delta CO3 ion[umol/kg]--Ref/source
   string dummy;
   double latitude, longitude, rockDepth, bathyDepth, CaCO3, fCaCO3, bSilica, Quartz, CO3i, CO3c, DCO3;
   string dummy2;
   //Use Overload>> operator
   friend istream& operator>>(istream& inputFile, Point& p);
};

//MAIN FUNCTION
std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point> > seamap;
seamap.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Point> > ("Nat", vector<Point>{}) );
seamap.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::vector<Point> > ("Sat", vector<Point>{}) );
//Repeat insert() for all other basins

Point p;
while (inputFile >> p && !inputFile.eof() )
{
    //Check if Southern Ocean
    if (p.latitude > Slat2)
    {
        //Check if Atlantic, Pacific, Indian...
        if (p.longitude >= NAtlong1 && p.longitude < SAtlong2 && p.latitude > SPLIT)
        {
            seamap["Nat"].push_back(p);
        } // Repeat for different basins
    }
    else
    {
        seamap["South"].push_back(p);
    }
}
//Partition basins by depth
for ( std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point> >::iterator it2 = seamap.begin(); it2 != seamap.end(); it2++ )
{
    for (int i = 500; i<=4500; i+=500 )
    {
        auto itp = std::partition( it2->second.begin(), it2->second.end(), [&i](const auto &a) {return a.bathyDepth < i;} );
    }
}
```

**Note:** `a` is of type `Point`. If I try to store `itp` into a structure such as a vector, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Point>::push_back(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Point*, std::vector<Point> >&)’
```

I'm just unsure of how to store `itp`. The end goal is to calculate the distance between a data point and all the other data points within a particular depth window (e.g. `1500m` to `2500m`). Any help for this novice would be appreciated.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can further narrow that code to present us a [MCVE] of your problem.

Comment: Apologies, what do you mean by a "simple sorting"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, of let's make a simple case which will tell your problem:

```
struct Point { int bathyDepth; }; // this is all, what you need to show    

int main()
{
    // some points
    Point a{ 1 }, b{ 100 }, c{ 1000 }, d{ 2000 }, e{ 3000 }, f{ 4000 }, g{ 4501 }, h{ 400 }, i{ 1600 }, j{ 2200 }, k{ 700 };
    // one map element
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point> > seamap
    { {"Nat", std::vector<Point>{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}} };

    //Partition basins by depth
    for (auto it2= seamap.begin(); it2!= seamap.end(); ++it2)
    {
        int i = 500; // some range
        auto itp = std::partition(it2->second.begin(), it2->second.end(), [&i](const auto &a) {return a.bathyDepth < i; });    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

> I'm just unsure of how to store `itp`.

To store, all you need to know is its type.
which is equal to `decltype(it2->second)::iterator`, as [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) returns iterator type of the container.

Since, your map's *key_type* is `std::vector<Point>`, it is equal to `std::vector<Point>::iterator`

You can test it programamically:

```
if (std::is_same<decltype(it2->second)::iterator, decltype(itp)>::value)
   std::cout << "Same type";
```

That means you can store `itp` in

```
using itpType = std::vector<Point>::iterator;
std::vector<itpType> itpVec;
// or any other containers, with itpType
```

---

> The end-goal is to calculate the distance between a data point and all
>   the other data points within a particular depth window (e.g. 1500 to
>   2500m).

If so, you need to simply sort the map's values(`std::vector<Point>`) according to the `bathyDepth` and iterate through it to find the required range. When you use `std::partition`, inside this loop

```
for (int i = 500; i<=4500; i+=500 )
```

the end effect/ result is the same as sorting at once, but you do it step by step. Also, note that to get a proper result using `std::partition`, you need a sorted `std::vector<Point>`.

For instance, see an<kbd>**[example code here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ESaEM1eVDFtZNA43)**</kbd>, which will print the range as you mentioned.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

struct Point
{
    int bathyDepth;
    // provide a operator< for std::sort()
    bool operator<(const Point &rhs)const { return this->bathyDepth < rhs.bathyDepth; }
};
// overloaded  << operator for printing #bathyDepth
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Point &point) { return out << point.bathyDepth; }

//function for printing/ acceing the range
void printRange(const std::vector<Point>& vec, const int rangeStart, const int rangeEnd)
{
    for (const Point& element : vec)
    {
        if (rangeStart <= element.bathyDepth && element.bathyDepth < rangeEnd) std::cout << element << " ";
        else if (element.bathyDepth > rangeEnd) break; // no need for further checking
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    Point a{ 1 }, b{ 100 }, c{ 1000 }, d{ 2000 }, e{ 3000 }, f{ 4000 }, g{ 4501 }, h{ 400 }, i{ 1600 }, j{ 2200 }, k{ 700 };
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<Point> > seamap
    { {"Nat", std::vector<Point>{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}} };

    for (auto it2 = seamap.begin(); it2 != seamap.end(); ++it2)
    {
        // sort it
        std::sort(it2->second.begin(), it2->second.end());
        //Partition basins by depth
        for (int i = 0; i < 4500; i += 500)  printRange(it2->second, i, i + 500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 100 400 
700 
1000 
1600 
2000 2200 
                      // no elements in this range
3000 
                      // no elements in this range
4000
```

Comment: Some questions/points: (1)-Is `itpVec` used? (2)-Could you explain the `operator<`, and how it is used? (3)-Is it wrong to assume that the overloaded operator `operator<<` prints out a bathyDepth "directly", instead of typing `element.bathyDepth`?

Comment: (1) No.. (sorry, forgot to delete) (2)See the [Relational operators here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) also read [this qestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882467/defining-operator-for-a-struct). (3) thats what `operator<<` does(just a syntatic sugar)

Answer (score 2):

[std::partition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) returns an iterator at the separation point between the groups of partitioned elements, which is the first element of the second group.  If you want to store this in another `vector`, the vector type should be

```
std::vector<std::vector<Point>::iterator>
```

The way you're using it, on subsequent calls to partition you don't want to partition the whole vector, just the part of it with the larger elements (because the early elements in the vector are now the lower elements, you don't need to include them in later partition calls since they're where they should be, and there is nothing in the `partition` description that says they won't be moved).  So the first element in later iterations of your `i` loop should be the `itp` iterator returned during the previous loop.

Comment: Do you mind giving me a few lines of code of what you mean exactly?