# How to define a custom key equivalence predicate for an std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to define a key equivalence predicate for a hash set I'm using, but the compiler keeps telling me that `function template "UniqueTable::table_key_equiv_pred" is not a type name` and I don't understand why.

I've defined my equivalence function as this:

```cpp
template<class t>
bool UniqueTable::table_key_equiv_pred(t a, node b) const
{
    return a == b;
}

template<>
bool UniqueTable::table_key_equiv_pred<int>(int a, node b) const
{
    return b && a == b->level;
}

template<>
bool UniqueTable::table_key_equiv_pred<node>(node a, node b) const
{
    return b && a && a->level == b->level && a->one == b->one && a->zero == b->zero;
}
```

And then instantiating a set using:

```cpp
auto hashtable = new std::unordered_set<node, std::hash<node>, table_key_equiv_pred>();
```

How do I define a predicate to be used as a type parameter to an `std::unordered_set`?

Comment: Are you attempting to use `table_key_equiv_pred()` as a callback?

Comment: I'm trying to be able to look up nodes via two different methods, either using an `int`, or a `node` as the key

Comment: The functions only job is to check if `node == node` is true. It's used by the set internally. Additionally `table_key_equiv_pred` is a template, not a function. `table_key_equiv_pred<node>` is a function.

Comment: but even using `table_key_equiv_pred<node>` still returns the same message

Comment: Why are you dynamically allocating a hash set and storing the result in a raw pointer?

Comment: Did you specialize `std::hash` for `node`? If so, then you have to do something similar here. Define an `operator()` that takes two `node`s and returns a `bool`.

Comment: When you get this to work, I don't think it will do what you want it to do. The hash of an `int` is likely not the same as an equivalent `node` (equivalent as defined by `table_key_equiv_pred<int>`) so `hashtable->find(4)` is not going to give you a level 4 node.

Comment: Perhaps you actually want `std::set` instead?

Comment: You might be right, I wasn't really sure how to tackle the problem to begin with, so my implementation might be a bit off, but that given, I'm still curious about the whole predicate thing

Comment: Also, the `auto` was just because I just threw this together, in the actual implementation it's not `auto`

Comment: Do all nodes have a unique level? I'm guessing they don't.

Comment: This is actually a pretty interesting question. I'm currently writing a very long answer!

Comment: Aside: It looks like `node` is an alias for a pointer type, why not have the set contain values instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third template parameter of [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) must be the type of a comparison object. `table_key_equiv_pred` is not a type. The default is [`std::equal_to`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) and is defined similar to this:

```
template <typename T>
struct equal_to {
  bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const {
    return lhs == rhs;
  }
};
```

You want to be able to search for `node`s in a set using `int`s or any other type. Doing this which `std::unordered_set` is not impossible, just kind of a pain. The problem is that `std::unordered_set` compares hashes first, then compares the actual objects second. If you want to search for an `node` using an `int`, then both of those must have the same hashes and compare equal.

From the code in the question, I've gathered that a `node` is more than just a `level` so the hash of an `4` is not going to be equal to the hash of a `node` with `level == 4` (unless you've defined `std::hash<node>` to just return `level`). This means that the custom comparison object is not even going to be used before it is concluded that `4` is not in the set even if a level 4 node is.

Being able to search for a node that compares to anything is tricky which a `std::unordered_set` because you need a "transparent" hash function. I suggest you switch over to a binary tree set ([`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)). This set compares elements for order (using a less-than comparison). This means that you only need to define a less-than comparison function.

It's rather uncommon to actually create a custom comparison object and do something like this: `std::set<node, MyCustomLessThan>`. What is usually done is defining a custom less-than operator for the type and then letting the default comparison object (in this case it's [`std::less`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less)) call the operator. Now you want to use the "transparent" less.

`std::less<int>` compares two integers. `std::less<node>` compares two nodes. [`std::less<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less_void) compares anything to anything and is called transparent less. `std::less<>` is defined similar to this:

```
template <>
struct less<void> {
  template <typename Left, typename Right>
  bool operator()(const Left &lhs, const Right &rhs) const {
    return lhs < rhs;
  }
};
```

So the data structure you want is `std::set<node, std::less<>>` but you still need to define the comparison between integers and nodes. You can do this by overloading the less-than operator.

```
// I'm not confident that these implementations are correct
// Nullable objects make this pretty tricky!
bool operator<(const node &lhs, const int rhs) {
  return !lhs || lhs->level < rhs;
}
bool operator<(const int lhs, const node &rhs) {
  return rhs && lhs < rhs->level;
}
bool operator<(const node &lhs, const node &rhs) {
  // I'll probably get this wrong so I'll leave this up to you!
}
```

Here's a full example (note that this uses C++14 features):

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>    

struct Node {
  int level;
  int thing;
};

bool operator<(const Node lhs, const int rhs) {
  return lhs.level < rhs;
}
bool operator<(const int lhs, const Node rhs) {
  return lhs < rhs.level;
}
bool operator<(const Node lhs, const Node rhs) {
  // A better way to do this is with std::tie
  // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16090720/4093378
  if (lhs.level < rhs.level) return true;
  if (lhs.level > rhs.level) return false;
  if (lhs.thing < rhs.thing) return true;
  if (lhs.thing > rhs.thing) return false;
  return false;
}

int main() {
  std::set<Node, std::less<>> set;
  set.insert({1, 91});
  set.insert({1, 87});
  set.insert({2, 43});
  set.insert({2, 10});

  // find a level 2 node
  // there's more than 1 level 2 node so you'll get the first one
  // see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find
  if (auto iter = set.find(2); iter != set.end()) {
    // prints "2 - 10"
    std::cout << iter->level << " - " << iter->thing << '\n';
  }

  // get a range of all the level 1 nodes
  // see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/equal_range
  auto range = set.equal_range(1);
  for (auto iter = range.first; iter != range.second; ++iter) {
    // prints "1 - 87" then "1 - 91"
    std::cout << iter->level << " - " << iter->thing << '\n';
  }

  // a neat thing about std::set is that all the elements are kept in order
  // that's how std::set differs from std::unordered_set!
  // this prints "1 - 87", "1 - 91", "2 - 10" and then "2 - 43"
  for (const Node node : set) {
    std::cout << node.level << " - " << node.thing << '\n';
  }
}
```

---

If you'd prefer to use `std::unordered_set` instead then you'll have to use a transparent hash function. **This is a C++20 feature.** Read the documentation I've linked for more information.

In order to search for a node with a given level, hashes for the level and the node must be compatible. This means that the hash of level 5 must be the same as the hash of a level 5 node.

Here's a full example (note that this uses C++20 features):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

struct Node {
  int level;
  int thing;
};

struct NodeEqual {
  struct is_transparent {};

  bool operator()(const Node lhs, const int rhs) const noexcept {
    return lhs.level == rhs;
  }
  bool operator()(const int lhs, const Node rhs) const noexcept {
    return lhs == rhs.level;
  }
  bool operator()(const Node lhs, const Node rhs) const noexcept {
    return lhs.level == rhs.level && lhs.thing == rhs.thing;
  }
};

struct NodeHash {
  using transparent_key_equal = NodeEqual;

  size_t operator()(const Node node) const noexcept {
    // note that the hash depends only on level
    // if lots of nodes have the same level,
    // then lots of nodes will have the same hash
    // this could lead to lots of equality comparisons
    return node.level;
  }
  size_t operator()(const int level) const noexcept {
    return level;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::unordered_set<Node, NodeHash> set;
  set.insert({1, 91});
  set.insert({1, 87});
  set.insert({2, 43});
  set.insert({2, 10});

  // find a level 2 node
  // see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find
  if (auto iter = set.find(2); iter != set.end()) {
    // prints either "2 - 43" or "2 - 10"
    std::cout << iter->level << " - " << iter->thing << '\n';
  }

  // getting a range of all the level 1 nodes isn't actually possible
  // there are a couple of tweaks required to make it possible
  // however, these tweaks will further reduce the performance of std::unordered_set
}
```

I can't actually test this example (because it's C++20) so I'm not sure if it's correct. I can only hope that I've read the docs properly!

`std::set` might actually be faster than `std::unordered_set` unless I know more about the uniqueness of `level`.

Comment: This is awesome and I really appreciate your enthusiasm, but I'm going to have millions of nodes, so using a O(log(n)) isn't going to cut it, I'm still accepting the answer though, because I realize now that I have to use a `struct` to create a predicate object?

Comment: @iggy12345 Whether `std::set` or `std::unordered_set` is faster will depend on how unique `level` is. Is there only node per level? Or maybe just 2 or 3 nodes per level? Or are there like 100 nodes on level 5?

Comment: @iggy12345 If there are a million nodes and there are (on average) more than 20 nodes per level (log_2(1000000) is about 20) then `std::set` has a better time complexity.

Comment: Well, in general I plan on hashing the pointers to the nodes themselves, there can be any number of nodes per level, except for level 0 which will only have 2. I wasn't planning on hashing with the level, since it's not unique, but being able to determine if any node is at a given level would be nice, which is why I'm trying to figure out how to lookup the node via level as well

Comment: @iggy12345 `std::set` has the same time complexity for looking up nodes and looking up levels. I don't think `std::set` is as slow as you think it is. If you want constant time lookup for both nodes and levels then you might need an additional container.

Comment: I'll have to discuss with my adviser, but I'm pretty sure he already tried using BSTs and they were too slow

Comment: @iggy12345 You could try using a sorted `std::vector` and then using `std::lower_bound` and `std::binary_search` for searching. This would improve cache locality so searching might be slightly faster than `std::set` because of this. You could put all the nodes of the same level next to each other in memory which could be useful. Although, insertions and deletions will take a hit if you use a vector. You can improve insertions and deletions by using a trivial relocation optimisation in a custom vector implementation but they still won’t be as fast as `std::set`.