# unordered_map: Lookup pair of std::string with a pair of std::string_view

Tags: c++

Given a hashmap that is keyed on a pair of strings, e.g:

`std::unordered_map<std::pair<String, String>, int> myMap;`

How could one do a lookup with a pair of std::string_view, e.g:

```
std::string s = "I'm a string";
std::string s2 = "I'm also a string";

std::string_view sv(s);
std::string_view sv2(s2);
myMap.find(std::make_pair(sv, sv2));
```

I guess that I need to define my own comparator somewhere, but I'm not sure where to begin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators

Comment: @Enlico the key is the only argument provided in my example... it's just that the key itself is a pair.

Comment: @notanalien, oh crap, I've misread the declaration of `myMap` :D

Comment: @Enlico, easily done!

Comment: Found a related post... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596768/stdunordered-mapfind-using-a-type-different-than-the-key-type/53530846#53530846

Sounds like there's no easy approach to this for unordered_map prior to C++20.

Comment: This should be the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58944520/how-to-define-a-custom-key-equivalence-predicate-for-an-stdunordered-set/58945096#58945096 but I can't get it to work. Here is the proposal on what to do: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0919r3.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With C++20's heterogeneous lookups this can be done (see documentation of [`unordered_map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find)). For this to work a hash functor and a equality functor have to be defined, e.g.:

```
struct hash {
    template <typename T>
    auto operator()(const std::pair<T, T>& pair) const {
        return std::hash<T>{}(pair.first) ^ std::hash<T>{}(pair.second); // not to be used in production (combining hashes using XOR is bad practice)
    }

    using is_transparent = void; // required to make find() work with different type than key_type
};

struct equal {
    template <typename A, typename B>
    auto operator()(const std::pair<A, A>& a,
                    const std::pair<B, B>& b) const {
        return a.first == b.first && a.second == b.second;
    }

    using is_transparent = void; // required to make find() work with different type than key_type
};
```

The type of the map then has to be changed to `std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int, hash, equal>` in order to use the defined functors.

`find()` now works as intended:

```
using namespace std::literals;

std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, int, hash, equal> map{};

map.insert({std::pair{"a"s, "b"s}, 42});

if (auto it = map.find(std::pair{"a"sv, "b"sv}); it != map.end())
  std::cout << it->second << std::endl;

if (auto it = map.find(std::pair{"x"s, "y"s}); it != map.end())
  std::cout << it->second << std::endl;

// prints 42
```

The implementation can be played with [here](https://godbolt.org/z/qoo1z4W35)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `unordered_map`, then you need to provide `Hash function` and `KeyEqual` for your custom key type, not the comparator for the key type which is needed only by sorted containers (such as `set/map`) or sorted container adapter (`priority_queue`).

In your example, the key type is `pair<string_view, string_view>`. The `std::pair` type already defines its `==` operator, but it provides no hash function. So we only need to define a hash function for the `std::pair` type. Fortunately, STL already provides the hash template specialization for `std::string_view`, which makes our task much easier. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <unordered_map>
 
struct Hash {
    size_t operator()(const std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view> &key) const {
        return std::hash<std::string_view>()(key.first) ^ std::hash<std::string_view>()(key.second);
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::pair<std::string_view, std::string_view>, int, Hash> myMap;

    std::string s = "I'm a string";
    std::string s2 = "I'm also a string";
    
    std::string_view sv(s);
    std::string_view sv2(s2);
    
    myMap.insert({{sv, sv2}, 1});
    
    // To print the map
    for (auto &[key, val] : myMap) {
        std::cout << "{" << key.first << ", " << key.second << "}: " << val << std::endl;
    }
    
    // To search
    auto it = myMap.find({sv, sv2});
    if (it != myMap.end()) std::cout << "Found key with value: " << it->second << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

output is:

```
{I'm a string, I'm also a string}: 1
Found key with value: 1
```