# I'm having an issue with my if statement logic

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Date {
private:
    int day, month, year;
public:
    Date(int, int, int);
    Date();
    friend istream& operator >> (istream&, Date&);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, const Date&);
    friend bool operator !=(const Date&, const Date&);
    friend bool operator ==(const Date&, const Date&);
    friend bool operator <(const Date&, const Date&);

};

Date::Date(int d, int m, int y) {
    month = m;
    day = d;
    year = y;
}

Date::Date() {
    day = 0;
    month = 0;
    year = 0;
}

istream& operator >> (istream& dates, Date& t) {
    cin >> t.day;
    cout << "Day: " << t.day << endl;
    cin >> t.month;
    cout << "Month: " << t.month << endl;
    cin >> t.year;
    cout << "Year: " << t.year << endl;
    cout << endl;
    return dates;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& dates, const Date& t) {
    dates << t.day << "/" << t.month << "/" << t.year << endl;
    return dates;
}

bool operator <(const Date& date, const Date& dat) {
    return (date.year < dat.year);
    return (date.month < dat.month);
    return (date.day < dat.day);
}

bool operator == (const Date& date, const Date& dat) {
    return (date.year == dat.year);
}

bool operator !=(const Date& date, const Date& dat) {
    return (date.year != dat.year);
        return (date.month != dat.month);
        return (date.day != dat.day);

}





int main()
{
    Date dates(0, 0, 0);
    Date dates2(0, 0, 0);


    cout << "Please enter a date: " << endl;
    cin >> dates;
    cout << "Your date is: " << dates;


    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter a date: " << endl;
    cin >> dates2;
    cout << "Your date is: " << dates2;

    cout << endl;

    if (dates != dates2) {
        cout << "Your date is not the same " << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Your date is the same " << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    if (dates < dates2) {
        cout << "Person 2 is older ";
    }
    else if (dates == dates2) {
        cout << "They we're born on the same date. ";
    }
    else {
        cout << "Person 1 is younger ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently having issues with my if-statement logic, when I input something like 11/26/2001 for my first date and 11/23/2001, it'll say that it is the same date and that they we're born on the same date. My goal is for my if-statement to go through Day-Month-Year and to check if they are the same and if all of those are the same then it should output, "You we're born on the same day" and "It's the same date" but right now it's only printing out those two lines of code when only one of the variables match each other.

Comment: `return` returns immediately, so you only compare the years even in the operators where you try to compare all parts. You want to read about the `&&` "logical and" operator.

Comment: You are aware that you can combine expressions of type `bool` using logical operators? `return date.year == dat.year && date.month == dat.month && date.day == dat.day;`? Furthermore assuming you're not going to implement the spaceship operator, you may want to define `!=` by using `==`: `bool operator!=(const Date& date, const Date& dat) { return !operator==(date, dat); }`

Comment: Also, your `>>` will only work if the parts are separated  with whitespace.

Comment: @fabian Or, more conventionally, `return !(date == dat);`.

Comment: In `istream& operator >> (istream& dates, Date& t)` you never use the input stream `dates` but instead read from `cin`. That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Also also, your code says "day-month-year" but your example dates seem to come from some backwards country that uses its own date format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining operator< for a struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882467/defining-operator-for-a-struct)

Answer (score 2):

```
bool operator <(const Date& date, const Date& dat) {
    return (date.year < dat.year);
    return (date.month < dat.month);
    return (date.day < dat.day);
}
```

Only the first `return` is ever used, the other two are dead code.

What you need to do here is make the returns conditional, like so:

```
bool operator <(const Date& date, const Date& dat) {
    if (date.year == dat.year) {
        if (date.month == dat.month) {
            return date.day < dat.day;
        }
        return date.month < dat.month;
    }
    return date.year < dat.year;
}
```

Comment: Or simpler: `return std::tie(date.year, date.month, date.day) < std::tie(dat.year, dat.month, dat.day);`

Comment: The same issue applies to the `==` and `!=` operators, too.

Comment: Note: In support of strict ordering, all of the other operators can be defined rooted by that `operator <` once it is nailed down. Ex. `operator ==` can simply be `return !(date < dat || dat < date);`, `operator !=` can then be either `return !(date == dat);`,  or `return date < dat || dat < date;`, etc. All you really need to make all the other logical operators work is a functional, fully tested `operator <`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau If you get that modern then just make it the spaceship operator too.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow `std::tie()` has been around since C++11.  The spaceship operator has only been around since C++20.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the operator == code compares only the year and returns true if the year matches.

```
bool operator == (const Date& date, const Date& dat) {
return (date.year == dat.year);
}
```

try this:

```
return ((date.month == dat.month) && (date.day == dat.day) && (date.year == 
dat.year));
```